# How to implement Theano.tensor.Lop in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

Recently, I want to rewrite some Theano coding in tensorflow. However, I encountered the problem that I do not know how to write Lop operator in tensorflow. The following picture is the API about Theano.tensor.Lop.

[image]

The following is the initial coding in Theano.

```
def svgd_gradient(X0):

    hidden, _, mse = discrim(X0)
    grad = -1.0 * T.grad( mse.sum(), X0)

    kxy, neighbors, h = rbf_kernel(hidden)  #TODO

    coff = T.exp( - T.sum((hidden[neighbors] - hidden)**2, axis=1) / h**2 / 2.0 )
    v = coff.dimshuffle(0, 'x') * (-hidden[neighbors] + hidden) / h**2

    X1 = X0[neighbors]
    hidden1, _, _ = discrim(X1)
    dxkxy = T.Lop(hidden1, X1, v)

    svgd_grad = grad + dxkxy / 2.
    return grad, svgd_grad, dxkxy
```

I have tried in this way, but there is something wrong with the dimension.

```
    def svgd_gradient(self, x0):
            hidden, _, mse = self.discriminator(x0)
            grad = -tf.gradients(tf.reduce_sum(mse), x0)

            kxy,neighbors, h = self.rbd_kernel(hidden)

            coff = tf.exp(-tf.reduce_sum((hidden[neighbors] - hidden)**2, axis=1) / h**2 / 2.0)
            v = tf.expand_dims(coff, axis=1) * (-hidden[neighbors] + hidden) / h**2

            x1 = x0[neighbors]
            hidden1, _, _ = self.discriminator(x1, reuse=True)
            dxkxy = self.Lop(hidden1, x1, v)

            svgd_grad = grad + dxkxy / 2
            return grad, svgd_grad, dxkxy

        def Lop(self, f, wrt, v):
            Lop = tf.multiply(tf.gradients(f, wrt), v)
            return Lop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
def Lop(output, wrt, eval_points):
    grads = tf.gradients(output, wrt, grad_ys=eval_points)
    return grads
```

(credit: [jhatford](https://github.com/jhartford/DeepIV/blob/master/deepiv/custom_gradients.py#L10))